# HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED when create new conda environment

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to create `conda` env with this code:

```
(base) C:\Users\huy>conda create -n pyenv python=3.8
```

Then I got this error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

I don't know why I get this error. Is it because I use my corporation network so it doesn't allow these connections?

I've found some answers about turn off the `ssl_verify` but I don't want to do that.

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
```